# How can you use compound assignment operators in C if you can't redefine variables?

Tags: c, redefinition, compound-assignment

Looking at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators) it says:

```
a -= b;
```

is the same as

```
a = a - b;
```

But when I try this in my C program I get the following error:

> ```
> "error: redefinition of 'a'".
> ```

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 10;
    int a -= 5;

    printf("a has a value of %d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

I received the following errors:

> ```
> my_prog.c:6:6: error: redefinition of 'a'
>        int a -= 5; 
>            ^
> my_prog.c:5:6: note: previous definition is here
>        int a = 10;
>            ^
> my_prog.c:6:8: error: invalid '-=' at end of declaration; did you mean >'='?
>        int a -= 5; 
>              ^~
> ```

I am using clang on Mac.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Missing semicolons.

Comment: In terms of context I've added my code and I think the title is quite clear.

Comment: `int a....` is a definition. But you have already defined it. You want an expression instead. Remove `int`.

Comment: The title is clear to an R programmer, because in R an assignment *is* a definition. In C, an assignment statement changes the value of an existing variable. It doesn't create a new variable, nor can it be used to change the type of an existing variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int a = 10` is a definition.

It combines the declaration of variable name and type (`int a`) with its initialization (`a = 10`).

The language does not allow multiple definitions of the same variable but it allows changing the value of a variable multiple times using an assignment operator (`a = 10` or `a = a - b` or
`a -= b` etc).

Your code should be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 10;    // declare variable `a` of type `int` and initialize it with 10
    a -= 5;        // subtract 5 from the value of `a` and store the result in `a`

    printf("a has a value of %d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are probably right. I didn't write C code this decade and I mixed them up a little bit :-(

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `a` is done like:

```
int a;
```

The initialization of `a` is done like:

```
a = 10;
```

You do both in the same expression:

```
int a = 10;
```

Now `a` is defined and initialized.

If you do the following:

```
int a -= 5;
```

After the previous expresssion, you are redefining `a`, hence the error.

You need only:

```
a -= 5;
```